# How to protect files that will be read/written in a deployed application

Tags: matlab, encryption

I am building a Matlab application to be deployed as a compiled executable file.

This application will need to read/write files in a library.
These files contain data and I want to protect them from being read by whomever uses this application. Without any protection, these files would be saved as mat files and could be loaded into Matlab workspace.

I've tried to search for some solutions for encryption. I found some people suggesting AES, but this method seems to have an intrinsic problem of safely storing the encryption key (which I didn't understand exactly why).

Given that I simply want to avoid the user of the application to have access to those data files, what would be the best approach for doing so? If AES is actually a good solution, is it safe to write the encryption key in the code to be compiled?

Comment: Wouldn't the user be able to use whichever part of your code loads that file (after possible decryption) to get that information anyway? Could you explain what kind of data you need for your app that you're trying to hide from the user?

Comment: @AndrasDeak The user would not have access to the data. The encrypted files would contain data to be plotted (which the user could see in the graph only) and also some other values that would be used as parameters in calculations (which should be completely hidden from the user).

Comment: @cinico Would using [pcode](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html) work?

Comment: @pkpkpk No. That format is not secure.

Comment: Don't save data files as `.mat` file. Write your own `save_data` and `load_data` functions, and use any kind of binary format you decide.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is functional encryption.

> In functional encryption, a user holding
>   the master secret key msk can generate a function key skf
>   corresponding to a function f; then, anyone having a ciphertext Enc(x)
>   and a function key skf can compute f(x), but learns nothing else about
>   the input x.

Note that Enc(x) is the encrypted data and f(x) is some function of the unencrypted data.

Source: https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/229.pdf

Unfortunately, even cutting edge implementations of functional encryption are still impractically slow and not easily generalized to a MATLAB program.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will follow a different approach. I will not allow to "write" in the encrypted files, which makes everything a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling an application, the MATLAB code files are encrypted; but not, as you’ve discovered, any extra files that you include.

If the data is not too large, consider saving it within a `.m` file rather than a `.mat` file. In other words, write a simple MATLAB function that returns your data, and has it hard-coded within the file. As this is now a code file, it will be encrypted as part of the compilation process.

You can even use the built in function `matlab.io.saveVariablesToScript` to auto-generate this file for you.

Comment: Thanks. This was the first solution I tried, but because the data I'm saving has to be a structure type, matlab.io.saveVariablesToScript won't work. It's true that I could extract all the data from all the fields, save them as individual variables, and then reconstruct the structure in the software. However, this has all sorts of inconveniences I would like to avoid...